# My IntelIJ does not see AfterTestExecutionCallback

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Just can not resolve a little problem.
I learn Sellenium in Java.
Now I learn about making a screenshots.
I want to use it only when my test fails.
I use jUnit 5 and I have a version :
`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

`
The problem is that I want to implement extention "AfterTestExecutionCallback"
but my IntelIJ simply does not see it :-/
I tried with other version of jUnit but the problem still remains the same.
Could You give me some advices please ?

Comment: What do you mean in - *my IntelIJ simply does not see it*? Maybe adding more details (maybe code) would help us to help you?

Comment: `<scope>` reduces the dependency to `src/test/java` folder. If you want to use it in `src/main/java` folder you need to remove `<scope>` which will default to `compile`

Comment: Fenio You resolved my problem. Now everything works correctly. Thanks a lot :-)